# Send and receive packet to and from nodes using pycore library in python script

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from core import pycore
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *

session = pycore.Session(persistent=True)
node1 = session.addobj(cls=pycore.nodes.CoreNode, name="node1")
node2 = session.addobj(cls=pycore.nodes.CoreNode, name="node2")
hub1 = session.addobj(cls=pycore.nodes.HubNode, name="hub")
node1.newnetif(hub1, ["10.0.0.1/24"])
node2.newnetif(hub1, ["10.0.0.2/24"])

packet = IP(src="10.0.0.1",dst="10.0.0.2")/ICMP()/"Hello World"
```

Here I have created two nodes i.e `node1` and `node2` which are connected to a hub  named `hub1`. `node2` is pingable from `node1` but I want to send packet (I made in last line of code) from `node1` to `node2` and process that packet after receiving at `node2`. Kindly Help me out!

Comment: **Beware** core tag is not meant for pycore, please read tag comment... I've removed it from that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a file over network you can use [NetCat](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/nc.1) on Linux. And in CORE, you can send shell commands to these nodes. Hence you can do something like the following.

```
node1.shcmd("nc -l 4444 > download.txt")
node2.shcmd("nc -w3 10.0.0.1 4444 < upload.txt")
```

The file *upload.txt* is assumed to be present on the Virtual node, *node2*, and is copied over to Virtual node *node1* under the file name *download.txt*

To create a file, you can again use *shcmd* to pass a shell command to create the file.

```
node2.shcmd("dd if=/dev/urandom of=upload.txt bs=1024 count=100")
```

This will create a 102kB file on *node2*. Make sure to use this command before you use NetCat.